# Url Rewriting in asp.net after postback

Tags: asp.net

How to do url rewriting in asp.net after the button click.
i have a .aspx page where i am going to write a name and the click on search button. after clicking on that button the searched value will be show in a gridview with all details and the Url should be shown like "http://www.somebloghost.com/Blogs/2006/12/10/" but the original Url is "http://www.somebloghost.com/Blogs/Posts.aspx?Year=2006&Month=12&Day=10".

Can u help me to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

This happens because asp.net submits a form on postback. A form has an action attribute which is your actual script by default

```
<form method="post" 
action="Posts.aspx?Year=2006&Month=12&Day=10" ...
```

You need to change it as follows

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;  
}
```

Read more http://ruslany.net/2008/10/aspnet-postbacks-and-url-rewriting/

Comment: but i will create that url after button click   Response.Redirect("find-a-doctor.aspx?name=" + txt_name.Text);

Comment: If you do Response.Redirect("find-a-doctor.aspx?something"); you do a redirect to that url, you do not "create" anything. If url must be different - use an appropriate redirect. e.g. Response.Redirect("doctor/something");